# When running the selenium script the default browser alert kicks in

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, alert, jenkins-agent

I have a few selenium (java) scripts written that need to test the logout scenario and there's this unexpected alert pops up when I'm running this script using a Jenkins job on a jenkins agent on another machine.
The problem is in our website, we have customized the alert to be "Changes that you made may not be saved" and the default Chrome browser alert is "Changes you made may not be saved". That is missing the "that" part.

And somehow, when I'm running my scripts, I see in my test results, I'm getting this popup that is not supposed to get. And when I'm running my scripts on my local machines, it seems fine and I can't manually reproduce a way to get this alert.

Does any of you have any idea why this is happening and why I can't reproduce this manually?

Thanks in advance.

the alert that is supposed to come-up,
[image: alert that is supposed to come-up]

the alert that is actually coming up,
[image: alert that is actually coming up]

Comment: Just click 'Leave' in that pop-up. Can you post the p[age HTML, after pop-up comes up?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.